# Getting a cron job to run every 30 minutes - using cron.hourly?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I would like to set up a `cron` to run a `shell` script every half an hour on my `Linux` server.

I have not set a cron job up before, I was planning to put the following in `cron.daily`:

```
*/30 * * * * /path/to/my/script
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cron.daily` does not run your scripts for every 30 minutes. You can create a new `crontab` entry for your requirement by doing

`crontab -e`

and then adding a line

```
0,30 * * * * /path/to/script
```

(or)

```
0/30 * * * * /path/to/script
```

for your requirement. You can confirm if your entry has been added to the list by doing `crontab -l` which lists all the scheduled `crontab` actions.

There are custom-strings you can use for scheduling actions and it does not apply at the 30-minute level.

```
@reboot  #Runs at boot
@yearly  #Runs once a year [0 0 1 1 *]
@annually  #Runs once a year [0 0 1 1 *]
@monthly  #Runs once a month [0 0 1 * *]
@weekly  #Runs once a week [0 0 * * 0]
@daily  #Runs once a day [0 0 * * *]
@midnight  #Runs once a day [0 0 * * *]
@hourly  #Runs once an hour [0 * * * *]
```

Using the above, something like below can be done.

```
@hourly /my-path/to/another-script
```

Comment: OK, so in my case the command I run is the following: crontab -e */30 * * * * /path/to/my/script       , is this the correct command? if not please update the answer with my command to run, thanks

Comment: @java123999: `crontab -e` opens up a  editor window where the new entry should be added. It also contains other entries if you have added it previously. Add the line there and save it. It is not a single command altogether.

Comment: Ok and is the syntax in my above comment correct for my command?

Comment: How does that syntax run it every half hour?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131339/discussion-between-inian-and-java123999).

Comment: @java123999: I fixed it now, wrongly added it for the 15 min crontab from my another answer.